# CoreLocation: know when user hasn't moved for n minutes

Tags: objective-c, core-location

I'm trying to achieve precisely this: have a method called when the user hasn't moved for a defined amount of time, even if the app is in background, and with a reasonable power consumption.

This could be easily done if I didn't care about the power issue, so i'm not very interested in solutions like setting up a location manager refreshing very often.

I found a way to do exactly the opposite, like determining when the user leaves a place, but I can't seem to find what i want to do.

If my case is not precise enough feel free to ask for more details.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute a repetitive NSTimer on background thread, check the age of last GPS update and take action appropriately.

For further optimisations you may need to disregard certain location-updates based on lat/lon, timestamp, speed. Tip: Speed/Course should be -1 when user is static (but these values could be -1 when user is moving).

Comment: I ended using geofences that i setup around user's location, and a timer to know if he has crossed it, but the GPS precision isn't always great so it doesn't always work, in brief: there is not good solution :( i'll mark yours as accepted though, you took the time to look into it, thx!

Comment: As per my experience, GeoFence relies on Wifi/Cell change events, for me also they are they are not a good solution to that problem. If time is not important factor you activate GPS for n minutes after m minutes. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263047/cllocationmanager-geo-fencing-startmonitoringforregion-vs-startmonitoringforsi/18446695#18446695